# How to display a post in theme template with its meta box data?

Tags: wordpress, metadata

I am displaying custom posts in wordpress but now I want the meta data saved with the post to also display. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You have to call a function **get_post_meta** and pass **post_id** and **meta_key** like this.

```
<?php $key_1_value = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'key_1', true ); ?>
```

For more Information https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/